# LocationServer | How can i retrieve the information from a service to my mainActivity?

Tags: java, android

I have a location service, i can make Toast of my current Location, but i dont know how to send this information to my MAP in my activity.

Can you please help me achieve that ?

the code where i need to send back is here :

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    new Notification();

    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createNotificationChanel() ;
    else startForeground(
            1,
            new Notification()
    );

    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
    locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(5000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
            Location location =  locationResult.getLastLocation();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Lat: "+Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + '\n' +
                            "Long: " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            currentCoor = new LLcoor(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());

            //locationArrayList.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

           /* for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
              location
            }*/
        }
    };
    startLocationUpdates();
}
```

i need to keep updating my position on the map. Im using azureMaps

If you need the full class code is here :

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
    public static ArrayList<LatLng> locationArrayList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;
    LocationCallback locationCallback;
    LLcoor currentCoor;

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        new Notification();

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) createNotificationChanel() ;
        else startForeground(
                1,
                new Notification()
        );

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                Location location =  locationResult.getLastLocation();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Lat: "+Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + '\n' +
                                "Long: " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                currentCoor = new LLcoor(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());

                //locationArrayList.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

               /* for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                  location
                }*/
            }
        };
        startLocationUpdates();
    }



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createNotificationChanel() {
        String notificationChannelId = "Location channel id";
        String channelName = "Background Service";

        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(
                notificationChannelId,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
        );
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelId);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("Location updates:")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Create static Callback or LiveData in LocationService and update the specific value that you want to use in your MainActivity.class:

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
    private static MutableLiveData<ArrayList<LatLng>> locationArrayListData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public static LiveData<ArrayList<LatLng>> getLocationArrayListData(){
            return locationArrayListData;
    }
    
    private void updateLocationList(ArrayList<LatLng> newList) {
            locationArrayListData.postValue(newList)
    }

.
.
.
.
}
```

And in your activity add this:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
.
.

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        .
        .
        LocationService.getLocationArrayListData().observe(this, {locationsList -> {
        //do What ever You Want With This 'locationList'
        }
        .
    }

.
.
}
```